# Using an instance of an object as a key in hashmap, and then access it with exactly new object?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a hasmap with a key object,

```
HashMap<Key, Object> test;
```

and make new Key("the same") as key..

so its like..:

```
test.put(new Key("the same"), someObject);
```

(without storing that key in a variable)

so.. after a while... i want to access the hashmap,
because i do not have the object, i've tried to make new Key("the same") and make it as a key.
But it didnt work.

How to make it work? (without saving the first object "key" in a variable)

So meanwhile, for now, im using String object as a key.

```
HashMap<String, Object>
```

Comment: It's hard to know what your question is asking. You might want to consider rewriting it... If you just want all the keys in your hashmap you can use the method `keySet()`...

Comment: Not duplicate : the other question does not directly deal with maps, but directly with `hashCode` and `equals` which may seem unrelated without the accepted answer. The accepted answer is just enough to understand the issue.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You need to implement `hashCode` and `equals` on `Key`.  The [default implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) of these methods simply checks for *instance* equality (in other words, two `Object`s will only be equal if they are in fact the same object).

### Further reading

[Effective Java - Methods common to all objects](http://fpl.cs.depaul.edu/jriely/ds2/extras/Chapter3.pdf)

Answer (score 43):

Your problem is likely that `Key` did not implement `hashCode()` and `equals()` correctly (or at all).  In order to be used as a `HashMap` key the class has to implement these two methods to reflect "equality" of two objects.

If you create two different instances with

```
Key a = new Key("xyz");
Key b = new Key("xyz");
```

and expect them to be equal and work in a `HashMap`, you have to override `hashCode()` so that it returns the same value in both instances, and `equals()` returns true when comparing them.

If the object identity is based on the string value, then

```
@Override
public int hashCode()
{
    return theStringValue.hashCode();
}
```

and

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o)
{
    return this.theStringValue.equals(o);
}
```

should work

Comment: If you are working in Eclipse, just right click and go to Source>Generate hashCode() and equals()… choose the attributes you want to include in these methods and the code will be auto-generated. A time-saver!

Comment: thanks @ruhong
I generated them easily with eclipse

Comment: And if you are using Lombok, it will generate such boilerplate for you with the [@EqualsAndHasCode](https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode)  annotation

Answer (score 9):

When a class does not override the `equals()` or `hashCode()` methods, the default implementations found on the `Object` class are used instead. In particular, `equals()` simply does a check for reference equality.

That immediately explains why your approach isn't working: the new `Key` object clearly isn't referring to the old `Key` object.

If you'd like to be able to specify a new instance with the same property, then you should override the `equals()` method with an implementation that meets your criteria for key equality. You should override `hashCode()` as well, to have full control over the key comparison process.