# Issue adding object to HashMap having Object as key

Tags: java

Why is the following code failing with compilation error?

```
class SampleClass{

}

public class DemoHashMap {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        SampleClass s1 = new SampleClass();
        SampleClass s2 = new SampleClass();

        Map<Object, Integer> counts = new HashMap<Object, Integer>();
        counts.add(s1, 1);
        counts.add(s2, 2);
    }
}
```

This code is not allowing me to add s1 & s2 to the hashmap. In the declaration for counts I have specified that the key can be Object.

Comment: Did you mean put rather than add?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using an instance of an object as a key in hashmap, and then access it with exactly new object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440380/using-an-instance-of-an-object-as-a-key-in-hashmap-and-then-access-it-with-exac)

Comment: When you post questions about errors, include the error text. Also, this question is trivially solvable by looking at the Map API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `add` method in Map.Use `put` instead.

```
counts.put(s1, 1);
```

See :- [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Answer (score 2):

There are few corrections to be done.

First there is no `add()` in `Map`, try `put()` instead.

Secondly it is recommended to override `hashCode()` and `equals()` of class `SampleClass` when using it as key.

Also since you are using generics it is recommended to declare map as:

`Map<SampleClass, Integer> counts = new HashMap<SampleClass, Integer>();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Map<SampleClass, Integer> counts = new HashMap<SampleClass, Integer>();
counts.put(s1, 1)
```