# How does put() function work in Java Map?

Tags: java, dictionary

I need to have clarified what's behind `map.put()` method's logic while updating.

By instance:

I have a Map which inside these few records:

```
{
  [K="key1", V="value1"],
  [K="key2", V="value2"],
  [K="key3", V="value3"]
}
```

If I wish to update record number two I'd write `map.put("key2", "value22")` and Java automatically replace `value2` with `value22`.

How could do that Java?

If the key had been a complex object composed by a few attributes...

```
{
  [K=new CustomKey("something1.1", "something2.1"), V="value1"],
  [K=new CustomKey("something1.2", "something2.2"), V="value2"],
  [K=new CustomKey("something1.3", "something2.3"), V="value3"]
}
```

...and I wish to update `value2` searching for it by a key with only one attribute valorized, how is possible to do something like this:

```
map.put(new CustomKey("something1.2"), "value22");
```

or do I need to provide exactly the entire `CustomKey` object?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440380/using-an-instance-of-an-object-as-a-key-in-hashmap-and-then-access-it-with-exac

Comment: You know the code is open source and you can read the code right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reached the final solution after some days: Implement a delegate which inside a custom `put()` method. In my opinion it's a quite AWFUL approach ciclyng a `Map` until some key has what you're looking for. Thought Java had something like `IEqualityComparer` in C# but I was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Search is done using the **whole key**, not only a part of it.

Internally there are two methods that are invoked on the key object and that are used to find the associated value. Those methods are `equals()` and `hashCode()`

If you write a custom class `CustomKey` for a more complex key you have to rewrite those methods (`equals()` and `hashCode()`), otherwise you will have unexpected results. Please refer to the javadoc documentation of [`class Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) where you will find the guidelines to write reliable implementations of those methods.

Answer (score 2):

> If I wish to update record number two I'd write map.put("key2",
>   "value22") and Java automatically replace value2 with value22.
>
> How could do that Java?

In a `Map` you need to understand the concept of `hashCode` and `equals` first. For every record first hash-code will be computed that will determine the bucket for this record. It is possible for multiple records to have same hash-code and in that case they will be stored in a linked list.

**How search for a record works?**

First of all hash-code will be computed to determine the bucket. Then for every record (entry) in the list corresponding to that bucket, it will be check for equality using`equals` method.The [default implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) of these methods simply checks for *instance* equality (in other words, two `Object`s will only be equal if they are in fact the same object).

> I wish to update value2 searching for it by a key with only one
>   attribute valorized, how is possible to do something like this:
>
> ```
> map.put(new CustomKey("something1.2"), "value22");
> ```
>
> or do I need to provide exactly the entire CustomKey object?

**Yes** you need to provide exactly the same key else it will not be able to locate the records in the map. The computation for hash-code will be using the complete key and not a part of it. You need to provide (override actually) implementation of these two methods.

Answer (score 1):

The code you described is already valid in Java. If you write

```
map.put(obj1, val1);
map.put(obj1, val2);

map.get(obj1); //Returns val2 with no errors
```

This is considered valid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

A map is a collection, it has no logic specific to your application.

For general information about the functionning of a map, pease look at [the java.util.Map javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put%28K,%20V%29)

Here it is said than adding an already present value replace the old one

Answer (score 0):

> do I need to provide exactly the entire CustomKey object?

Yes, you have. Keys are compared via `equals` method of underlying objects. So even if you have another 1-arg constructor for `CustomKey` constructed object will not be *equal* to *key* object in `Map` and `put` method will not replace *value* object.