# Best approach to have multiple key-value pairs, in a Value of an outer key

Tags: java, hashmap, key-value

I am trying to create a dictionary type record, that holds for example key="Book name" and value= (key="price": $250, key="qty": 10). What would be the easiest way to achieve this is Java ? I have tried by creating a separate class object for they Value.

```
public class book_info {
int price = 0;
int qty = 0;

public void  book_info(int qty, int price){
    this.qty = qty;
    this.price = price;
    }
}
```

and creating a HashMap instance;

```
Map <String, book_info> items = new HashMap<String, book_info>();
items.put("Book1", new book_info(600, 20));
items.put("Book2", new book_info(200, 30));
items.put("Book3", new book_info(100, 50));
```

This works fine but is there any other alternate way by NOT using a separate class object, instead by just adding multiple key-value pairs in the initialization of HashMap like this;

```
Map <String, <<String, Integer>,<String, Integer>>> items = new HashMap<String, <<String, Integer>,<String, Integer>>>();
```

Comment: Your best approach is to use OO and model the domain as you started to do. However, I would also add a title to the `BookInfo` object. It also gives you much greater flexibility in the future.

Comment: I think you're looking for `Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>`. But what you have now is much better.

Answer (score 0):

your question was probably already been answered, what your trying to do is use an object as the maping key, so instead of having [key, object] you want to have [object1, object2] and each object can be a map of  which at the end will make them [[key1, value1][key2, value2]] for more details on using objects as keys see answer:

[Using an instance of an object as a key in hashmap, and then access it with exactly new object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440380/using-an-instance-of-an-object-as-a-key-in-hashmap-and-then-access-it-with-exac)